# How to add local dependency to npm project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies

How do I make javascript project depended of local javascript project using `package.json`? The project I must depend on doesn't have any npm configuration files in directory.

Comment: You publish it to npm. Otherwise you just include it where you need to and forget about `package.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency you wish to specify in the dependent's `package.json` must itself have a properly constructed `package.json`. Otherwise, it does not function as an npm package and you cannot specify it in another package's `package.json` in a meaningful way.

If you are able to add a `package.json` to the dependency, then you can include it as a local package by specifying its [local path](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths). Otherwise, if the dependency cannot contain a `package.json`, I recommend creating a symlink to it in the dependent's directory.